# How do I change drawerlayout open and close icon and keep animation same time

Tags: android

How do I change drawerlayout open and close icon and keep animation same time,the problem slow me a few days , can somebody help me?

Comment: show your code what you tried..

Answer (score 0):

You can use latest navigation drawer that will this thing automatically.

```
http://www.sitepoint.com/material-design-android-design-support-library/

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/primaryColorDark"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu" />
```